# Postfix allow SASL-authenticated users to send from any IP address

Tags: smtp, postfix, sasl

I understand that I need SMTP on port 25 to receive email, but I do not want this to be a relay port.
Instead I would port 587 to be used for registered (SASL-authenticated) users to relay email from any IP address, through my server, and to any email server (e.g. GMail, Yahoo).

I have set up Postfix to receive email, and authenticate users, but I am utterly confused about the difference between port 25 and 587, and how to use one for receiving and one for relaying.

Here is the relevant part of my `main.cf` currently.

```
myhostname = mx.example.com
mydomain = example.com
#myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = localhost localhost.localdomain
mynetworks_style = host

smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, 
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_unauth_destination

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, 
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        # reject_unauth_destination is not needed here if the mail
        # relay policy is specified under smtpd_relay_restrictions
        # (available with Postfix 2.10 and later).
        reject_unauth_destination
        reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rhsbl_reverse_client dbl.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rhsbl_helo dbl.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rhsbl_sender dbl.spamhaus.org
```

And `master.cf`.

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n - - - - smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch
```

Unfortunately I get this error when trying to send on port 587 with my mail client from a different IP address.

```
NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]: 553 5.7.1 <test@example.com>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user test@example.com; from=<test@example.com> to=<test@domain.tld> proto=ESMTP helo=<[192.168.1.3]>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per-port configuration is done in `master.cf`, not `main.cf`. The default Postfix configuration files already have good example settings, they just need to be uncommented. Port 587 is labelled as the `submission` port there (port 25 is of course `smtp`).

Your settings could be somewhat simplified. In `main.cf`, specify the default policy (for port 25) only as `recipient_restrictions`, nothing more than that is necessary:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks
    reject_unverified_recipient
    reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org
    reject_rbl_......
    permit_auth_destination
    reject
```

In `master.cf`, override it by removing the previously set restrictions and allowing unrestricted relaying for authenticated users:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```